How do you send a message to all connected hosts using the Python socket message?
I want to be able to send a packet to all devices connected to a socket object (server-side).
Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve (server-side):
import socket

def server(s): # s is the socket object
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        msg = c.recv(4096).decode()
        # some way of sending what is received to all hosts connected?


Python also provides websockets which is much easier to work with.

There are only two devices "connected" to TCP socket object, you and your peer. If you have a server serving multiple connections (like a chat room) then your server must save to a list every connected socket object returned from the accept() call. If you want to send something to all the clients, like a message received from one client, then you must iterate over the list of sockets and send the message to each one.

Please clarify what you don't understand. The answer below assumes you have a list of connected clients, but perhaps that's the part you don't understand.

Thanks to the comments, I found what I was looking for.
I made a list with all the socket connections and iterated over each instance to send a message to the clients.

Assuming you have a list called clients, containing the c from c,addr = s.accept(), then:
msg: bytes = c.recv(4096)
for client in clients:
    client.sendall(msg)


Why decode then convert to bytes? Also, this is not reliable because you cannot guarantee that the entire message has been received (even if it's less than 4Kb)

@SIGHUP I'm just extending their code simply to show an example of how you can send data over the socket to the clients. I wasn't focused on making the code efficient

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
